# Insert multiple rows via while loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a grid/map based on coordinates, and instead of inputting a million rows manually I'm trying to figure out a way to do it in just a few queries but I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around how to do it.

What I want it to do is enter a row for each coordinate to create a 1000x1000 square with each square in the grid being a row I just need some help figuring out how to actually put this in a query.

I ran this code twice one time each with the while loop +1 each time for $onecoord and then once with it adding +1 to $twocoord I knew it wouldn't fully fill out the table it only added 999 coordinates each time.

```
$onecoord = 1;
$twocoord = 1;


while($twocoord < 1000) {
    mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO coords (x, y, walkable, image, spawn) 
                         VALUES('".$onecoord."','".$twocoord."','1','grass2.png','0')") 
or die($link->error); 

    $twocoord = $twocoord + 1;
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
. . . . . . . . . . .
```

That is what the coords I'm getting look like I want to make it so it is a full square + completely filled in with each dot ='s a row in the database.

Comment: It's because what you are doing is: *As long as `$twocoord` is smaller than 1000...* So if you do `while($whocoord <= 1000){...` instead, it will add 1000. Because then you're saying: *As long as `$twocoord` is smaller than or the same as 1000*

Comment: I know that's not the problem I'm trying to solve I need it to create a 1000x1000 grid filling in all 1 million rows and coordinate combinations I just can't seem to wrap my mind around how I can do it without doing this query combination 1000 times.

Comment: It depends on what exactly must be changed? Like, give an example of how the first 1000 will be, then the second and perhaps even the third. If we know how the result should look like, it'll be a lot easier to create a solution for it.

Comment: I edited my question with an example, if that helps a bit. I know I can accomplish this if I run my query with changing one of the coords manually and running it 1000x but that would be a horrible amount of work.

Comment: Alright nvm, I ended up figuring it out on my own, I'll post my solution in my question.

Comment: Don't! If you found a solution to your own question, answer your own question

Comment: Better. Now in 2 days you'll be able to mark your own solution as the accepted answer. That way your question won't remain unanswered forever :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, this is the solution.

```
$onecoord = 1;
$twocoord = 1;

while($twocoord <= 1000){
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO coords
(x, y, walkable, image, spawn) VALUES('".$onecoord."','".$twocoord."','1','grass2.png','0')") 
or die($link->error); 

$twocoord = $twocoord + 1;

if($twocoord == 1000 && $onecoord <= 1000){
$twocoord = 1;  
$onecoord = $onecoord + 1;  

}
}
```